# Avoid parsing Xrandr output

Tags: linux, go, x11, xrandr

i need to get information from xrandr into my software. Suppose thats my output from `xrandr -q`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1968, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+309+1200 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 277mm x 156mm
   1366x768      60.02*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96 
   1280x720      60.00 
   1024x768      60.00 
   1024x576      60.00 
   960x540       60.00 
   800x600       60.32    56.25 
   864x486       60.00 
   640x480       59.94 
   720x405       60.00 
   680x384       60.00 
   640x360       60.00 
DP1 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00 
   1600x1200     60.00 
   1680x1050     59.95 
   1280x1024     60.02 
   1280x960      60.00 
   1024x768      60.00 
   800x600       60.32
   640x480       60.00 
   720x400       70.08
```

The data I want is the possible solutions together with the possible refresh rates. So far my software reads the capabilities from `/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1` and so forth but I can't find any information about the possible refresh rates for any solution. Any hint on that?

I'd also like to know if and how the monitors are arranged in respect to each other, meaning when setting things up if commands like `--above`, `--below`, `--left-of`, `--right-of` have been used. Is there any way to determine that?

What I really don't want to do is to parse the xrandr output from terminal. So the question is if anyone has any idea how to do this in a nice way. I'm working in a Go environment but did not find any package which solves my problems so far.

Any help welcome.

Comment: The language is called Go, not golang ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [`github.com/BurntSushi/xgb`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xgb/) package
which is a pure Go implementation of [XCB](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/),
and [it has access to the `randr` facility](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xgb/blob/master/examples/randr/main.go).

Comment: thanks for your response. xgb seems valuable to me. unfortunately there is a bug in the lib respectivly in X. check out [this](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xgb/issues/20) which make it impossible to retrieve the refresh rate. so, any further recommendation?

Comment: got it. one can calculate the refresh rate via the ModeInfo.

Comment: Hm, from the onlooks of the bug, it appears that the server does not send the information which `xgb` expects to locate in the `randr` request. Unfortunately, my knowledge of X internals is clearly lacking to suggest what component is really at fault here.